# Correct use of programmatic WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean, spring-config

`AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` the following when calling `refresh()` as is suggested in the javadoc

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'x'
```

> Javadoc for: AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext#register
>
> Note that AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.refresh() must be called in order for the context to fully process the new classes.

The bean `x` is defined in the `rootContext`. Without calling `refresh` there is no error and everything is autowired and starts correctly.

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // Root context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootContext.class);
        rootContext.refresh();

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // REST servlet
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext restContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        restContext.register(RestConfig.class);
        restContext.refresh(); // <--------- Throws exception
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic restServlet = servletContext.addServlet("rest", new DispatcherServlet(restContext));
        restServlet.addMapping("/rest/");
    }
}
```

Am I missing something configuration wise?

---

**EDIT:**

`RestConfig` essentially looks like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "foo.bar")
public class RestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Autowired
   private X x;
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

There's no evidence of using `refresh()` in the javadoc for [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) that does contain a good example.

Comment: it looks like the problem is in your RestConfig class. Please share that.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd posted. I'm pretty sure there's no problem there as the entire application runs and executes fine when not calling `refresh` in the initalizer

Comment: You have 2 Spring contexts that are unrelated, yet you are trying to inject from one to the other. I think you need to call. `restContext.setParent(rootContext)` before the refresh

Comment: I can buy in to that argument, yet, I'm assuming that's done by the `ContextLoaderListener` since autowiring works when not invoking `refresh`

Comment: ContextLoaderListener knows about rootContext, but not about restContext